# How do I get all the ip addresses sending packets to the machine in C++?

Tags: java, c++, sockets, networking, java-native-interface

I am writing a program in Java that requires me to get all ips and ports sending packets to the current machine and I was told that Java can not do  that and that I need to use a Java Native Interface with C or C++ in order to do this.  So I am asking **how do I get all the ips connecting/sending packets to the current machine?  I do not want the local ips or LAN ips**

Answer (score 0):

There is a library which does this. It uses a JNI wrapper but you don't have to write yourself.

Current code is here https://github.com/jpcap/jpcap

Was http://jpcap.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I tried using that, but in one of the readme files it said to download something and the download did not exist.

Comment: @Forseth11 Sounds like something you need to solve.  I have used this library before to successfully listen to an adapter in promiscuous mode to get all packets.